# How do I say "You're making me hungry?"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

A friend was describing some food she's making.  I wanted to say "You're making me hungry" or "That makes me hungry."  What's the proper way to say this?

My first thought was to say something like:

> Me das hambre.

But I tried Google translate, and it gives (at least) three options, depending on the exact phrase I try to translate:

Google Translate thinks:

> You're making me hungry. → Usted me está haciendo hambre.
>   You make me hungry. → Usted me hace hambre.
>   That makes me hungry. → Eso me da hambre.

Should I stick with `Me das hambre`, or should I try `Me haces hambre`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's "me das hambre" or "me estás dando hambre", even "me está entrando hambre" without involving the other person specifically.

Comment: +1 I would use "me está dando hambre"

Comment: I'm happy to know my gut feeling was on the right track. :)

Comment: Although you will be completely understood, I don't think it's 100% right since there's a subtle difference (as in English) "(tú) me das hambre" = Yourself is making me hungry.
"(ello) me da hambre" = something is making me hungry (listening to you talking about food)

Comment: Me haces tener hambre.

Comment: I would not use the first option as it suggests that the other person (and not his actions) is what makes you hungry and feels a bit weird/dirty. It would not be the case if you specify the reason. E.g: `Me das hambre comiendo aquí.` With the other options no further explanations should be necessary, it is harder to misunderstand them.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a literal traslation, but in my opinion this is the more appropriate: 
"You're making me hungry" = "Estás haciendo que me dé hambre" 
 "That makes me hungry." = "Está haciendo que me dé hambre"

Answer (score -2):

"Me estás haciendo dar hambre" is the correct way. if you say "Me das hambre" she'll probably understand you want to eat her.

Comment: @Lucas técnicamente podríamos formular la oración hipotética _estás haciendo que yo haga que otros tengan hambre_, por lo tanto, _haces que de hambre_ (no me suena completamente agramatical). Esto obviamente no era lo que pedía el OP, pero podría llegar a ser válido!

Comment: @clinch, tienes razón. Reedito mi comentario: _me estás haciendo dar hambre_ means _you are making me make others hungry_ or sth like that, gramatically possible but weird in any context (except for some juicy people)