# How do I say ‘Watching him eat makes me hungry’?

Tags: traducción

How do I say ‘Watching him eat makes me hungry’ in Spanish?

> Lo veo comer me tiene hambre.

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/how-do-i-say-youre-making-me-hungry?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Verlo comer me da hambre** or 
**Verlo comer me pone hambriento**

The first one uses the noun 'famine/hunger' and the second one uses the adjective 'hungry'

Comment: The first one would be much more common, in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

> Watching him eat makes me hungry.

1. To properly translate this sentence requires some basic understanding of both English and Spanish.  The word "watching" looks like a verb here, which leads the Spanish beginner to try to conjugate it as a verb, but it's really not a verb.  It's a noun.  Consider a slight variation, which helps to illustrate this point:

   > Ice cream makes me hungry.

   In English, when we use a verb as a noun, as in "watching", we use the [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund):

   - I like *swimming*.

   In Spanish, when we use a verb as a noun, we use the [infinitive](http://spanish.about.com/od/infinitives/a/infinitive_noun.htm).

   - Me gusta *nadar*.

   We actually use the same construct in English as well, and if you mentally convert the gerund form of a verb-as-a-noun into the infinitive in English before translating, the translation into Spanish will be easier.

   - I like *to swim*.

   So armed with this bit of knowledge, we can rule out the conjugation of "ver" in your first attempt.  This leaves us with the infinitive form, **verlo** in place of **lo veo**.
2. To make one hungry is an idiomatic expression in Spanish. It doesn't translate literally.  I don't know of any way to know this, except to learn it.  To make one hungry in Spanish is to "give hunger", or **dar hambre**.

So that leaves us with:

> **Verlo** comer me **da** hambre.

Literally:

> To see him eat gives me hunger.

Answer (score 1):

"De sólo verlo comer me da hambre"

More cryptic but academic:

"No bien lo veo comer, me da hambre"