# Is this the proper way of using "lo que"? "Lo que menos me gusta es viajando por avión"

Tags: pronombres

I have this sentence in a speech, and I don't think it makes sense:

> Lo que menos me gusta es viajando por avión.

I'm trying to say:

> What is least pleasing to me is traveling by airplane.

I'm not sure "lo" is necessary...

Comment: Correctamundo!!

Comment: "Lo que menos me gusta es VIAJAR en avión" es la frase correcta. "Lo que" es correcto, no así "viajando"

Answer (score 8):

The *lo* is correct and necessary.

It's a stand-in for the thing that is pleasing to you.  Without it, *que* doesn't get parsed as what we in English think of as *what*, rather as *that* and the entire clause becomes the subject, rather than just the thing that pleases you.  In other words, without the *lo*, your sentences starts of saying *That it is least pleasing to me is…* (or in other words, *The fact that it is least pleasing to me is…*)

You do, by the way, need an infinitive instead of a gerund with your last bit: *...es viajar por avión*.

Comment: or _viajar **en** avión_. Great answer.

Comment: @Diego para mí suenan bien tanto "por" como "en avión"

Comment: @clinch, para mi suenan bien los dos pero me inclino más por "**por**" en ese contexto. Mi sugerencia es un **or**, no una corrección a la respuesta. "Me gusta más viajar **en** avión porque es más rápido, pero hicimos el viaje **por** barco, porque salía más barato".

Comment: @clinch que sepa yo, lo normal es que las personas van en avión (viajes) y los objetos van por avión (correo) aunque es posible intercambiar. También serviría vía avión, pero me suena muy técnico ya que muy poca gente usa vía hoy en día como preposición.

Comment: Why can't “qué” be used?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a direct translation  you would write.

> Lo que menos me gusta es viajar en avión.

Notice  how you do not use Spanish endings "-ando", "-endo" because you are describing something you do not like to do.

However here "lo" is necessary. If you do not use "lo" you would need to write:

> No me gusta viajar en avión.

Comment: notice the diference between using `is traveling by airplane.` and `is to travel by airplane.` in spanish you can not do that sustitution

Comment: Your explanation for using the infinitive is imprecise. In English, we can use either the infinitive or the gerund form of a verb as a noun--in Spanish only the infinitive us used. This is why "viajar" is the proper translation, it has nothing to do, *per se* with being something one likes or dislikes--it has to be with the verb being used as a noun. See [more here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4564/12).

Answer (score -1):

You may think of "lo" as the literal English equivalent if "it".  Think about how this sentence would appear in straight English translation:

*It that least pleases me is ....*

This, of course, is more colloquially expressed in English as "*What* least pleases me is..."

Comment: The correct English translation of "lo que" is "That which", and that makes perfect sense in this context: "That which least pleases me..."

Comment: I have never heard anyone say "it that least pleases me", so I googled it and this post is the first result. The rest of the results contain punctuation or a different structure that allows that sequence of words to work. Are you a native speaker?